# Wildfly 8.1 - set system property without standalone.xml

Tags: java, configuration, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

To overcome the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029973/beans-xml-file-and-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-jbas011859-naming-c), I have a requirement to set a system property,

```
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
```

Due to environment constraints, I can not use standalone.xml or the web interface in WildFly 8.1 to do so.  Is there a way to achieve this from within my EAR or WAR file?

I would imagine this would be done using jboss-deployment-structure.xml or jboss-web.xml, but can't find any references to this.

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Doing it in the EAR or WAR is already to late; according to the question/answer you link to it needs to be set at Java startup time using the -D command line flag. So it needs to go in the standalone startup script, or in a JAVA_OPTS environmental variable. Both require modifications to the server environment.

Comment: @Gimby you should just put that as the answer as you're correct :)

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I didn't want to do that since I'm basically just parroting what the linked answer clearly implies... but I guess flagging this as a duplicate is also not correct. I'll trust your judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in the EAR or WAR is already too late; according to the question/answer you link to it needs to be set at Java startup time using the -D command line flag. So it needs to go in the standalone startup script, or in a JAVA_OPTS environmental variable. Both require modifications to the server environment.

Comment: Thanks @Gimby.  I was hoping there way a way around it, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

Not using an EAR or WAR but if you are using JBoss or Wildfly you can use a SAR to do this.  SARs are unique to the JBoss community and run as a service inside of your container, starting prior to all WARs and EARs.  I have previously used a SAR to set system properties from  references stored in my DB but you could easily also load them from a static string or a flat file. If you are using maven, there is also a jboss based SAR module for creating it at compile time.  You can find steps to create a sar at http://www.javabeat.net/sar-service-archive-file-in-jboss/.

Comment: Thank you. This is really nice if you want to bake your own redistribution of WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "The native management API"
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/The+native+management+API

Comment: Not from the deployment though. It will be too late.

Comment: Yes it is true, but it modifies configuration file and will be applied on the next server restart.